# Counting Multiple Moving Objects

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I want to count moving objects.

I can find the object's centroid:

```
for i in range(len(contours)):
        if len(contours[i]) >= 5:
           ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[i])
           (center , axis, angle) = ellipse      
           cx,cy = int(center[0]),int(center[1])     #centroid
           ax1,ax2 = int(axis[0])-2,int(axis[1])-2
           orientation = int(angle)
```

I draw a line:

```
Line = 100
cv2.line(frame, (Line, 0), (Line, 500), (255, 0, 0), 1)
```

Check If centroid cross the line:

```
distance = int(cx - Line)
if (distance == 0 or distance == 1):
    counter += 1
```

---

**The problem is;**

If I check `distance` for both `0` and `1`, sometimes object counted twice.

On the other hand If I check only `0` or only `1`,  sometimes I miss the object.

*How can I increase the accuracy of counting?*

---

**Edit:**

Objects moving only on `-X` direction. Green dots represents center of the object.

Initially, `Line` at 100th px on `X` axis and object are coming from `0th` pixel and goes on `-X` axis.

I'm subtracting `X` coordinate of `Line` from center pixel's `X` coordinate of object. If they cross, then they must be at same `X` axis. If they are at same `X` coordinate, their subtraction must be equal to `0`.

Sometimes `Line` and `Object's` `X` coordinate doesn't cross, it seems object jump the `Line`.

*If It's not a good solution for counting multiple moving objects, what could it be?*

[image]

Comment: I don't think your issue is reproducible from what you've shared. I'm not sure how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: Create a list of eggs whose leftmost point is on one side and rightmost point is on the other. Remove and count them once that is no longer the case (both points are on the left side)?

Comment: Actually, make that leftmost point and the centroid instead of rightmost

Comment: @ilvthsgm Hi, I am facing same issue. Have you figured out the solution for this? If yes, please share.

Comment: @Jazz I used Kalman Filter. It’s little bit heavy but it works great